# Error in creating Endpoint in Rest API

Tags: rest-api, rest, apexrest

I have created an Endpoint using the @Rest Resource(urlmapping='')  followed by apex class having a method as HTTP POST which returns a string when the endpoint is called...i have called this endpoint from other org ..then i am getting error as 404 i.e. not found. please can you explain where i am going wrong and  help me to create the endpoint without oAuth.

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure whats inside your URL mapping. Assuming it as a randomtext like "callmyservice" - your class has the below text at the top : 
**@Rest Resource(urlmapping='/callmyservice/*')**

Considering your server instance as **na8** he end point will be something like : 
https://na8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/callmyservice”.

Hope this helps!